# replace string between two quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to turn a string `str = "hello, my name is \"michael\", what's your's?"` into `"hello, my name is <span class="name">michael</span>`

How can I do that in javascript? I know how to do str replace, but how do I get the content that I selected/replaced with it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8):

```
str = "hello, my name is \"michael\", my friend's is \"bob\". what's yours?";
str.replace(/"([^"]+)"/g, '<span class="name">$1</span>');
```

Outputs:

```
hello, my name is <span class="name">michael</span>, my friend's is <span class="name">bob</span>. what's your's?
```

Comment: oh, i've always wondered what the $1 means... I guess it gets selected text by a regex?

Comment: @mazlix yes, the $1 gets the contents of the first capturing group. i.e. things enclosed in `()`. In this case: `[^"]+` == 1 or more non-`"` enclosed in `""`

Answer (score 0):

While @davin's answer is correct, I assume you'll want to deal instances of double quotes.

```
var str = "hello, my name is \"michael\", what's your's? Is is \"James\" or is it blank:\"\"";
```

A `*` in place of the `+` will suffice:

```
/"([^"]*)"/g
```

Although you could discard it altogether with a simple first-parse search and replace:

```
str.replace(/""/,"")
```